Finding the covariance of two related variables
Problem:
Let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be uncorrelated random variables. Find the covariance between $U_1 = Y_1 + Y_2$ and $U_2 = Y_1 - Y_2$ in terms of the
variances of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.
Answer:
Let $\sigma^2_1$ be the variance of $Y_1$. Let $\sigma^2_2$ be the variance of $Y_2$.
\begin{align*}
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(U_1 U_2) - E(U_1)E(U_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(( Y_1 + Y_2)( Y_1 - Y_2 )) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 + Y_2Y_1 - Y_1Y_2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
\end{align*}
I do not know how to continue. Please help.
The book's answer is:
$$ \sigma^2_1 - \sigma^2_2 $$
Here is an updated and I believe correct answer.
Answer:
Let $\sigma^2_1$ be the variance of $Y_1$. Let $\sigma^2_2$ be the variance of $Y_2$.
\begin{align*}
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(U_1 U_2) - E(U_1)E(U_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(( Y_1 + Y_2)( Y_1 - Y_2 )) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 + Y_2Y_1 - Y_1Y_2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1 + Y_2)E(Y_1 - Y_2) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - (E(Y_1) + E(Y_2))( E(Y1) - E(Y_2)) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2) - E(Y_1)E(Y_1) + E(Y_2)E(Y_2 ) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2) - E(Y_2^2) - E(Y_1)E(Y_1) + E(Y_2)E(Y_2 ) \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &= E(Y_1^2) -  E(Y_1)E(Y_1) - ( E(Y_2^2) - E(Y_2)E(Y_2 ) )  \\
cov( U_1, U_2 ) &=  \sigma^2_1 - \sigma^2_2
\end{align*}

You can use

$E[Y_1 + Y_2]E[Y_1 - Y_2] = (E[Y_1]+E[Y_2])(E[Y_1]-E[Y_2])= (E[Y_1])^2 - (E[Y_2])^2$
$E[Y_1^2 - Y_2^2] = E[Y_1^2] - E[Y_2^2]$
$\sigma_1^2= E[Y_1^2]-(E[Y_1])^2$ and  $\sigma_2^2= E[Y_2^2]-(E[Y_2])^2$

